# How to get information from database file, and retrieve that information in the website file?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm in the process of doing a "mock" website for a class and I'm having issues getting the information from my database file, to the actual page in my site. I should mention that I'm a total php newb. Also there isn't any security yet.

`I'm calling the connection from another file, so I didn't include that.`

database function:

```
function GetProductsByCategory($categoryID) {
        global $conn, $productsResult;
        echo $categoryID;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodCategory = '$categoryID'";
        $productsResult = $conn->query($sql);
    }
```

Website File:

```
//In the head of website file
<?php
      $categoryID = "87";
      if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
          GetProductsByCategory($categoryID);
      } else {
          // Fallback behaviour goes here
      }
?>

//In the body
<?php while ($row = $productsResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Just trying to get information from the database file
            echo '<div>'.$row["prodName"].'</div>';
      }
?>
```

I should mention that nothing throws an error, It echos out the category ID at the top, but inside the `<div>` it just doesn't show anything.

Comment: You need to return $productsResult from the function, then use this return value in your while loop

Comment: It's easier to return the result instead of declaring it as global.

Comment: are you sure in your database id is a string?

Comment: and what is the `$categoryID` that is echoed out?

Comment: I changed the database method to return `$productsResult` and now I get an error in the div: `Notice: Undefined variable: productsResult in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\Products.php on line 47

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\Products.php on line 47`

Comment: Then you may be hitting the `else`, because `$_GET['category']` is not set.

Comment: return the $productsResult in function GetProductsByCategory and save the response in some variable and use that variable

Database function:

function GetProductsByCategory($categoryID) {
        global $conn, $productsResult;
        echo $categoryID;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodCategory = '$categoryID'";
        retrun $conn->query($sql);
    }

website file:

$categoryID = "87";
      if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
          $productsResult = GetProductsByCategory($categoryID);
      } else {
          //
      }
now run foreach on $productsResult

Comment: I put an echo in the `else` clause, and it's not calling. So I'm definitely in the main clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function and save the result in a variable:

```
$result = GetProductsByCategory($categoryID);
```

then inside the function:

```
$productsResult = $conn->query($sql);
return $productsResult;
```

then your while loop should use this returned result (i.e., `$result`):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ... }
```